# Set Woocommerce product attributes

Tags: api, woocommerce, product

everyone,

I have a "small" problem here for which I have not yet found a suitable solution. I hope you have the right food for thought for me.

We are currently in the process of introducing a new ERP (Weclapp - www.weclapp.com), which will transfer the product data to Woocommerce via ERP's own API. Many of our products are quite similar and available in different versions (industrial parts with different alloys, angles, sizes, etc.). Our product range includes tens of thousands of different products, so it is essential to offer the user a filtering option. Although it would be possible to create a variant article in the ERP, we would like to avoid this if possible (due to the circumstances that this would create on the part of the ERP). Unfortunately, the API does not allow us to transfer product attributes directly to single articles. The API only offers the possibility to transfer your own fields (created in the ERP) and output them in Woocommerce in the tab "Additional Information" or alternatively to fill an existing field in Woocommerce (can also be a custom field) via Meta Data Key.

I found the Meta Data Key for the product attributes, but I only have the possibility to transfer simple values like "Stainless Steel", "180°", "2SN" etc. The Meta Data Key for the product attributes looks a bit more cryptic and would be replaced by the simple values.

Does anyone have an idea or a workaround how I can use the values of the additional fields of the ERP as filterable data in Woocommerce?

Thanks a lot already!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your post to include the name of the ERP you are using so that some user who has familiarity with it might be better equipped to help you. As it stands, this post is ambiguous because we do not know which ERP system you are trying to use and each of them will implement variance slightly differently. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've edited the post above and added the name of our ERP system. I'm not sure what further information they might need. If there is anything missing please let me know and I will add the corresponding information.